# Not understanding the return value from scanf

Tags: c

I have the following C program, and I don't understand the return value from `scanf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int p,n1,n2;

    p=scanf("%d %d",&n1, &n2);

    printf("%d", p);
    return 0;
}
```

`p` is assigned the return value from `scanf`.
When I provide values for `n1` and `n2`, the value of `p` is always 2. I don't understand why the value is always 2 regardless of what numbers I provide for `n1` and `n2`.

Comment: Hi Scotia! Welcome to this site. Coding questions such as this one should be asked on StackOverflow.com, not here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`scanf` returns the number of values read, which in your case is 2.

Comment: Would you please elaborate?

Comment: @Scotia `scanf` returns *the **number** of values read* not the values themselves.

Answer (score 3):

`scanf()` returns the number of values read *except* for `%n` values.

"Execution of a %n directive does not increment the assignment count returned ..." C11dr §7.21.6.2

```
int p,n1,n2;
int n;
p=scanf("%d%n%d",&n1, &n, &n2);
// p  takes on the value of 2, not 3, should n1 and n2 successfully scan.
```

If no conversion occurs, `scanf()` returns `EOF`.

"The fscanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs before the first conversion ..."

```
char buf[100];
int n;
while ((n = scanf(" %99[^\n]", buf)) != EOF) {
  handle(buf, n);
}
```